Oracle SQLPlus taking exclusive session and not allowing to run update statements from .Net application
I connected via sqlplus like this:
sqlplus user/password@SID

I have a .NET application which also connects to the same database using the same user and password. But once sqlplus is connected, it was unable to run any update statements.
So, the following code doesn't do anything. It just hangs and control is not returned to program if I check it using breakpoint.
command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Does sqlplus take exclusive session once connected?


Does sqlplus take exclusive session once connected?

No, but one session (not necessarily specific to SQL*Plus) may lock rows in a table and other sessions can then hang while they wait for the lock to be released if they want to modify the same rows.

For example, if, in the SQL*Plus session, you updated rows and did not COMMIT the changes and then want to update the same rows in the C# session then that session may be waiting for the lock on that row to be released by the SQL*Plus completing its transaction.
Either COMMIT or ROLLBACK your changes in the SQL*Plus session and then the C# session should stop hanging.
